Why celery took GBs to store chord task result
I am running one simple celery task
task_list = [a.s(id) for id in id_list]
a_callback = callback_function.s()
chord(task_list)(a_callback)

so when the task list is lets say 1-2L items, the table django_celery_results_chordcounter is in GBs within some moments!

The only thing that can explain it is that your task returns some large object, ofc. Either that, or you have way too many small tasks in your chord, each returning some value.

we have too many short tasks (around 2L) which returns some value which we need to send at the end of the task and tasks chord

2L like two litres?

No around 2,00,000 number of tasks

What is that number? 200000 (two hundred thousands)?

And what is the size of "some value" (in bytes) ?

yes the number of tasks are around 200, 000 and each tasks returns bool value. so what i suspect is each task is also maintaining  state of rest of other tasks in django-celery-result table!

@DejanLekic , I was wondering that by any chance the above setup holds value of each metadata for each records? is it the reason why we cant use celery chord feature for such large number of transactions?
